# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' - workaround

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-8cf38df798b5> in <module>()
      1 x =  df[['text']]
----> 2 x['subjectivity'] = df.text.apply(lambda x: TextBlob(str(unicode(df[['text']]))).sentiment.subjectivity)
      3 df.head()

/Users/keenek1/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3589             else:
   3590                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3591                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3592 
   3593         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-34-8cf38df798b5> in <lambda>(x)
      1 x =  df[['text']]
----> 2 x['subjectivity'] = df.text.apply(lambda x: TextBlob(str(unicode(df[['text']]))).sentiment.subjectivity)
      3 df.head()

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 551: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have tried to get around it by using different encoding definitions and also even writing the dataframe back to csv, with utf-8 encoding.

What can I do?

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import pandas as pd
path = 'Tweets.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path, delimiter=',', header='infer')
df.to_csv('tweets_encoded.csv', encoding='utf-8')
df = pd.read_csv('tweets_encoded.csv', delimiter=',', header='infer', encoding='utf-8"')
```

I tried looking up the encoding using chardet

```
rawdata=open('Tweets.csv',"r").read()
chardet.detect(rawdata)
{'confidence': 0.5471323391929904,
 'encoding': 'Windows-1254',
 'language': 'Turkish'}
```

The error comes when running

```
x =  df[['text']]
x['subjectivity'] = df.text.apply(lambda x: TextBlob(str(df[['text']])).sentiment.subjectivity)
df.head()
```

Comment: Have you tried to encode the bytes in utf-16 or utf-32?

Comment: Can you please show the full traceback of the error so that we can see in more detail what part of the three offending lines you've shown wants to decode something as ASCII?

Comment: Hey thanks for your responses, I have updated the full error. I tried utf-16 and 32 but got UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf32' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-3: code point not in range(0x110000)

Comment: Now that chardet suspects that the encoding is "Windows-1254", did you try that?

Comment: I did, but the error didn't change :(

Comment: I am not that familiar with the pandas library, but have you tried to avoid encoding with utf-8 twice?

Comment: Yeah, doing that was just a test, saving the df to csv and then re-reading the cab in utf-8 format. Hmmm